# Makefile from QMake won´t finish compiling(pictures)

Tags: c++, qt, makefile

So I am making a GUI app with Qt, and I made Makefile from qmake. Now the problem is when I run `make` server seems to doing something for a long time. I am unable to kill it by `^D` or `^X` or anything. I need to shut down the terminal. Here is picture from start of `make`: 
[image]

And then after some miliseconds just this appears:
[image]

I let the process live for like 30 minutes without results. Where the problem could be?

Comment: In a separate terminal, can you find the PID of your make job [use ps or pgrep] and run a tool like pstree to see which processes it has started?

Comment: The .pro file for qmake is quite big but there are no special things just headers and sources. I cant get the pid for some reason(there are only 2 processes and none of it is make). The 7. line is : `if (deck.getActualCard() == nullptr)`

Comment: ps -aux |grep make : `Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See /usr/share/doc/procps-3.2.8/FAQ
user  8468  0.0  0.0 103404  2236 pts/154  SN+  14:03   0:00 grep make`

Comment: Maybe I cannot get it trough second terminal. Can I run make on background and then check PID?

Comment: It seems you are on OSX, so type `aux` instead of `-aux`

Comment: Not OSX that is some linux or freeBSD. But I will try.

Answer (score 0):

Well running it from putty instead of bitvise showed the errors from transition.cpp .Thank you all.